# nib property is nil after is has been assigned - swift

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView that I want to load it inside another ViewController. In `viewDidLoad` of my VC, I load my UIView which is `ContactUs` and it works fine.

```
var nib : ContactUs!
nib = ContactUs()
nib.tag = 100
nib.delegate = self
nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContactUs", owner: nib, options: nil)?[0] as! ContactUs
nib.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: self.view.bounds.width , height: 120)
self.view.addSubview(nib)
```

As I want my UIView to be reusable, i wrote my ContactUs class like this:

```
protocol ContactUsDelegate {
    func closeWindow()
}

class ContactUs: UIView {

    var delegate : ContactUsDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!
    @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if delegate != nil
    {
        delegate.closeWindow()
    }
    else
    {
        print("are you kidding me!")
    }
}
}
```

and in my VC, I added `ContactUsDelegate` to class and put this function in it:

```
func closeWindow()
{
    print("here we are!")
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }else{
        print("No!")
    }
}
```

The view loads correctly, but when i press cancel button, it prints "are you kidding me!" which means `delegate` is `null` . why delegate says it's nil when i said it to be self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContactUs", owner: nib, options: nil)?[0] as! ContactUs`

Returns you a new "ContactUs" view entity. Try to set delegate after this line.

Your code should be:

```
var nib : ContactUs!
nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContactUs", owner: nib, options: nil)?[0] as! ContactUs
nib.tag = 100
nib.delegate = self
nib.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width:         self.view.bounds.width , height: 120)
self.view.addSubview(nib)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var nib : ContactUs!
nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContactUs", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! ContactUs
nib.tag = 100
nib.delegate = self
nib.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: self.view.bounds.width , height: 120)
self.view.addSubview(nib)
```

It s because your assigning a new instance of ContactUs after setting the tag and delgate